# Does it matter which Database.getQueryLocator method I use in regards to soql limits?

Tags: batch, governorlimits

I usually use `Database.getQueryLocator('soql string')` when creating batch classes but I also see there's an overloaded method that takes a List of records, meaning I can use `Database.getQueryLocator([<soql>])` instead.

If the records I'm querying contain over 50k records would the second method throw a SOQL limit error? If it would throw an error, what is the benefit to using the second method if it's prone to limit errors?

The reason I'm even asking this is because apex does some under the hood magic when it comes to [soql for loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm) so I'm curious if the second approach does something similar avoiding the 50k record limit but I don't see this [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_getQueryLocator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inline query syntax isn't the same as a list of objects. You get up to the full 50,000,000 record limit when using a query that supports a cursor (e.g this won't work with aggregate result queries, with a limit of 2,000 rows returned),

This depends on context, though. The limit is 1 million in a read only visualforce page, and 50,000,000 for a Batchable start or Queueable class (but only 50k per execute method). Triggers would still be subject to the normal 50,000 transaction limit.

In fact, I always recommend using this form, because the compiler can type check your fields and objects to validate that your query cannot fail at runtime due to typos, and also creates a hard link so that metadata changes won't break your code.

To use this type of cursor, put the query directly in the method parameter:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id From Account]);
```

Edit: OP asked a follow up question if this still holds true using a selector method that returns a list of records instead of using an inline soql query.

Unfortunately, it does not. However, you can have your selector method return the constructed SOQL string and pass that to the query locator.

`Database.getQueryLocator(new SelectorClass().getBatchQueryString())`

Comment: Excellent, thank you for confirming!

Comment: Here's an additional question, if I'm using a selector framework that enforces FLS and returns a List of records would I still have this benefit or would I be better off having the selector method return the constructed soql string instead of the records?

Comment: @TemporaryFix there's no benefit if you're using a query builder pattern.